# Proof Critique: If Graph G=(V,E) is self-complementary, prove that G is connected

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I assume for contradiction, that graph G is disconnected.

Let G' be the complement of G

Let Kn be the complete graph, Kn = G U G'

If G is disconnected, then to obtain the complete graph, Kn, there must exist edges in G' (not in G) to connect all vertices so that

Kn= G U G' is a complete graph

Contradiction, we assumed G is isomorphic to G', i.e. a 1-1 edge correspondence, thus G must be connected.

Any comments appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see much of a proof here. First of all, what do you mean by "there must exist edges in $G'$ (not in $G$) to connect all vertices"? Second, what exactly is the "contradiction" that you supposedly arrived to? I don't see it.

Comment: The first three lines make sense. Everything after that is incomprehensible. (By the way, the theorem you are trying to prove follows from a more general theorem: for **any** graph $G,$ at least one of the graphs $G$ and $G'$ is connected. Of coure, if $G$ is isomorphic to $G',$ this means that both are connected.)

Comment: 1) I'm trying to say that if G is disconnected, then there is at least 1 edge missing from it to connect all vertices. So, in order to obtain the complete graph, Kn, (by taking the union of the two) G' must contain that missing edge.      
2) The contradiction this implies is that G and G' are not isomorphic, i.e. they have a different number of edges. But I assumed that they were at the beginning of the problem. I could try to clarify what I mean with a picture of K_4 if my explanation is still too convoluted.